# numpy, named columns

Tags: python, numpy

Simple question about *numpy*:

I load 100 values to a vector `a`. From this vector, I want to create an array `A` with 2 columns, where one column has name "C1" and second one "C2", one has type `int32` and another `int64`. An example:

```
a = range(100)
A = array(a).reshape( len(a)/2, 2)
# A.dtype = ...?
```

How to define the columns' types and names, when I create array from `a`?

Comment: Your best bet is to wrap the array (actually 2) and a list of names into a container class and use that.

Comment: @Keith: do you mean any particular class (I am new in numpy)?

Comment: No, I mean one you create. Then you delegate operations to your arrays from methods you define in your new class. Also define a `__str__` method to pretty-print your arrays with headers.

Comment: Do you need to have your data in one array? That is, are you going to perform operations on the whole array at once (even though you state you want different datatypes per column), or are you going to perform different operations per column? In the latter case, there is perhaps no reason to put them in one numpy array instead of multiple different arrays with different names. And as per Keith's suggestion you could combine those separate arrays in a class or a named tuple.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

NumPy structured arrays have named columns:

```py
import numpy as np
    
a = range(100)
A = np.array(list(zip(*[iter(a)] * 2)), dtype=[('C1', 'int32'),('C2', 'int64')])
print(A.dtype)
```

```
[('C1', '<i4'), ('C2', '<i8')]
```

You can access the columns by name like this:

```
print(A['C1'])
# [ 0  2  4  6  8 10 12 14 16 18 20 22 24 26 28 30 32 34 36 38 40 42 44 46 48
#  50 52 54 56 58 60 62 64 66 68 70 72 74 76 78 80 82 84 86 88 90 92 94 96 98]
```

Note that using `np.array` with `zip` causes NumPy to build an array from a temporary list of tuples. Python lists of tuples use a lot more memory than equivalent NumPy arrays. So if your array is very large you may not want to use `zip`.

Instead, given a NumPy array `A`, you could use `ravel()` to make `A` a 1D
array, and then use `view` to turn it into a structured array, and then use `astype` to convert the columns to the desired type:

```
a = range(100)
A = np.array(a).reshape( len(a)//2, 2)
A = A.ravel().view([('col1','i8'),('col2','i8'),]).astype([('col1','i4'),('col2','i8'),])
print(A[:5])
# array([(0, 1), (2, 3), (4, 5), (6, 7), (8, 9)], 
#       dtype=[('col1', '<i4'), ('col2', '<i8')])

print(A.dtype)
# dtype([('col1', '<i4'), ('col2', '<i8')])
```

Comment: You are right. http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.4.x/reference/arrays.dtypes.html

Comment: brilliant and not unknown but amazingly not common knowledge which it should be.

Answer (score 11):

I know this is an old question, but a more recently available option would be to try using [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org). The [DataFrame](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html#dataframe) type is designed for structured data like this, where columns are named and can be of different types.