# Is there a way in python to have a phantom class like access to a numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a bunch of position samples that come in to me as a 2D numpy array.  Rows of ts, x, y, z

I usually access them in a for loop like

for sample in data:

```
 ts = sample[0]
```

but I'd much rather access it like I would with a class like

```
for sample in data:
     ts = sample.ts
```

Now I know I could covert it to a class and have an array of position objects, but the problem is later I'm going to want to do numpy like operations on this data like matrix multiplication and there the class gets in the way. I guess I'm looking for a way to access my data using a meaningful name rather than depending on remembering what's at position 0,1,2,3... all the time. So I was wondering if there was some sort of view into the data I could make that would do it or something like that.

Comment: Maybe you should use pandas instead of numpy

Comment: Would `sample['ts']` be OK?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7038659/202168

Comment: The duplicate link suggests `structured array` with named `fields`.  There are accessed with `sample['ts']` style.  A variant on this the `recarray`, with also allows attribute like access, `sample.ts`.  In practice most are happy with the indexed style, and don't need the attribute version.